# Migration from ASP.NET Websites to ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We have an application that developed as the ASP NET website and We wanted to migrate the application to ASP NET Core. We don't want to rewrite the entire website at once and launch it. We are planning to migrate page by page and deploy it in parallel to the same application. We wanted to hear from experts that this plan would work or Is there any best way to address this migration.

- If this scenario is possible, how would both applications share the authentication cookies between them as we wanted to run the application parallelly? - NOTE: Our application supports SSO with ADFS using WS-Federation.

Comment: It is impossible for "page by page" migration, as page based WebForms is not supported by ASP.NET Core at all. If you in fact meant URL by URL/controller by controller, edit your question to make it clear. Each of your followup questions like "how would both applications share the authentication cookies between them as we wanted to run the application parallelly" have been discussed and answered already, so don't waste time here.

Comment: .NET Conf 2019 had a [session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZuqMrWSano) regarding this. May or may not work for you.